# EXEC statement in SQL stored procedure's cursor loop

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, cursor

I have the following code in my stored procedure.  It seems sometimes, the execute statement doesn't execute for some @ID values.  Any ideas?  What happens if the EXEC statement takes long time in the cursor loop?  In other words, is EXEC statement synchronous or asynchronous? Thanks!

```
declare @ID int
declare cur CURSOR LOCAL for

    select ID
        from WQ 
    where  CONVERT(DATE, DEPLOY_DT) = CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE())
        AND STAGE_ID = 6

open cur

    fetch next from cur into @ID

    while @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 BEGIN

        exec uspUpdPublishByWQID @ID

        fetch next from cur into @ID
    END

close cur
deallocate cur
```

Update:

Thanks Hans.  I do catch exceptions, if something goes wrong and save it to database.  I see the following error today:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Timeout expired.  The
>   timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the
>   server is not responding. ---> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception
>   (0x80004005): The wait operation timed out     at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception,
>   Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)     at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject
>   stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)     at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior,
>   SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream,
>   BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject
>   stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)     at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteNonQueryTds(String
>   methodName, Boolean async, Int32 timeout, Boolean asyncWrite)     at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.InternalExecuteNonQuery(TaskCompletionSource`1
>   completion, String methodName, Boolean sendToPipe, Int32 timeout,
>   Boolean asyncWrite)     at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()     at
>   BCPublish.Publish.PublishTasks() 
>   ClientConnectionId:10786fb0-c091-446f-adca-7f359131f731

Just wondering, if there is a timeout error, why it worked for some IDs???

Comment: If you could describe what you want to do or post the code for `uspUpdPublishByWQID`, we could help you get rid of the `CURSOR`.

Comment: Edit your stored procedure and start it with `PRINT @id` or something similar.  I'm willing to bet you will find that is does execute once per row in your cursor.

Comment: It does print all ID values.  Does the control flow skip EXEC statement if it takes long time?

Comment: Felix, I inherited this code and cannot change it at this time.

Answer (score 0):

> It seems sometimes, the execute statement doesn't execute for some @ID values. Any ideas?

Try to add a PRINT statement or so to debug which IDs are being used.
I'd also test run the SELECT statement to see what IDs are supposed to be used.

> Are EXEC statements synchronous or asynchronous?

EXEC statement is always *synchronous*.
Your EXEC statement might START, for example, a SQL Agent job that can run asynchronously but that is probably beside the point.

> What happens if the EXEC statement takes long time in the cursor loop?

Your cursor will take longer to run...

Answer (score 0):

Since the process works some of the time the code is functional.  Look at the SQL server performance in the areas of:

1. index fragmentation
2. VLF
3. I/O

Ask the senior DBA to trace the process and record the performance counters.